# Angular Dynamic Search of words from a JSON file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am implementing a search in Angular whereby a json file is uploaded dynamically and I want to make it possible for a person to type some words to be searched against the uploaded json file.
My controller for upload is :

```js
app.controller('myController' , function ($scope , $timeout){
    $scope.beforeIndex = {};
    $scope.container = {};
    $scope.set = {};
    
    $scope.searchResults = [];
    $scope.message = {
        status: false,
        message:false
    };
    $scope.loadFile = function () {
        $timeout(function () {
            $scope.beforeIndex[$scope.file.name] = angular.copy($scope.file);
        } , 200);
    }
```

Upload works successfully.Any guidance on doing a dynamic search will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to take a look to this? https://github.com/ghiden/angucomplete-alt

Comment: No.I am going through it right away.

Comment: I can see the json is declared statically in the code.Which technique can I use to enable dynamic loading of json file to be searched against?

Comment: Take a look to its dynamic feature... where you can set a endpoint from where retrive data

Comment: Let me do that.

Answer (score 0):

if you want take  a look to this angular plugin:

```
https://github.com/ghiden/angucomplete-alt
```

and maybe use it like this (to retrive data from a remote endpoint)

```
$scope.remote_url =  "http://localhoat:3000/api/Artist/Search/?word=";


 <div angucomplete-alt
                             id="artist"
                             placeholder="Search Artist ..."
                             pause="400"
                             selected-object="searchArtist"
                             remote-url="{{ remote_url }}"
                             title-field="nome"
                             remote-url-data-field="data"
                             minlength="1"
                             input-class="form-control form-control-small"
                             match-class="highlight">
                        </div>
```

Hope it helps you .. and put in the right direction